# Custom route with optional parameter still returns exception null when parameter has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following View code which returns the showid from the current item and calls action to load the information of the show from an other action and display it in a partial view.`

```
@{var bodyText = @x.title.ToString();
                        Int16 showid = Convert.ToInt16(@x.showId);
                     <img src=@Html.Action("_ShowThumbnail", "Thumbnail", showid);
```

My route is as follows

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Thumbnail",
            url: "Thumbnail/_ShowThumbnail/{showid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Thumbnail",  action = "_ShowThumbnail", showid = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And my action

```
 public ActionResult _ShowThumbnail(Int16 showid)
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                var programs = webClient.DownloadString("
```

With debug I see the right value for showid in all locations but still get a Null exception. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you aren't matching your `showid` variable to your `{showid}` placeholder. Instead you are just passing an `Int16` value as the anonymous parameter object to the [`Html.Action()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423(v=vs.118).aspx) method, which won't do anything.

The second issue is that although the `{showid}` placeholder is optional in the route, the method parameter is still an `Int16` so is required - so you either need to make it nullable (`Int16? showid`) or add an `ActionResult _ShowThumbnail()` version of the method to your controller.

If you want to fix the `Html.Action()` call, you need to set up the anonymous object correctly:

```
<img src="@Html.Action("_ShowThumbnail", "Thumbnail", new { showid = showid })" />
```